# HighCharts acessing x-axis labels with jquery

Tags: highcharts, x-axis

I am new to working with HighCharts. I am working on a project that was started by someone else but not finished. In this project the user will have a chart that spans multiple days but only wants to use certain sections of it. The user wants to use the bottom navigation 1 bar which lets you zoom into certain time spans to move around the chart to save different version of the chart. They will press the save button to save the state of the chart which they are currently viewing. I need a to know if it is possible if you can access the labels in the x-axis of the line chart so I can save the time positions they are looking at? Do HighCharts provide any way of getting output from the Navigation 1 bar?

I have accessed the x-axis labels with jquery and can see the data I need using ('#fn.init').prevObject[0].all.chartContainer.innerText, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to go about it. Is there a better way to do this?

Chart Configuration:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container',
                        {
                            navigator: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            scrollbar: {
                                enabled: false
                            },
                            chart: {
                                renderTo: 'container',
                                type: 'spline',
                                zoomType: 'xy',
                                panning: true,
                                panKey: 'ctrl',
                                events: {
                                    load() {
                                        const chart = this;
                                        chart.showLoading('Loading, Please Wait ...');
                                        setTimeout(function() {
                                                chart.hideLoading();
                                            },
                                            1500);
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            boost: {
                                useGPUTranslations: true,
                                turboThreshold: 1000
                            },
                            rangeSelector: {
                                buttons: [
                                     $('#heatingStart').val(), 
                   toDateAdd($('#heatingStart').val(), 1, 'H'));
                                    graphicinfo(RecipeId, $('#heatingStart').val(), toDateAdd($('#heatingStart').val(), 8, 'H'));
                                    graphicinfo(RecipeId, $('#heatingStart').val(), toDateAdd($('#heatingStart').val(), 1, 'D'));
                                
                                    {
                                        text: 'All',
                                        events: {
                                            click: function() {
                                                graphicinfo(RecipeId, $('#ReportStartDate').val(), $('#ReportEndDate').val());
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            legend: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Time (Hrs)'
                                },
                                categories: categoriesX
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                tickWidth: 1,
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Temperature (°F)'
                                },
                                labels: {
                                    format: '{value:.0f} °F'
                                },
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                opposite: true
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Thermocouples Temperature Data'
                            },
                            series: termocouplesdata
                        });
```

Comment: To access in xAxis labels you can do it with [xAxis.labels.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter) or [xAxis.labels.format](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.format). I need see your chart configuration to understand your description, this is template that you can use [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/g9rszdhb/).

Comment: I added the chart configuration but I don't want to set the labels in the chart. I need to retrieve theme so that I can use them in an ajax call.